# 'find'  across directories named .../dirnameXX/... with XX variable

Tags: shell-script, find

I am executing this command to find certain files in specific directory:

```
find ./rgs/test/maesXX/master/stdlist -name \*.extract \
     -mtime +30 \! -size 0 -exec ls -lrt {} \;
```

where XX could be any number between 1-100.

Can I use a regex for this purpose? How would I do that? Are there other ways?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass more than one path to `find`, so the best way (IMHO) is to let the shell do the expansion.

If you don't have other directories starting with `maes` there, then this should suffice, and is simpler:

```
find ./rgs/test/maes*/master/stdlist ...
```

But if you really need to match that pattern exactly, you can do

```
find ./rgs/test/maes[0-9][0-9]/master/stdlist ...
```

for `maes00` -- `maes99`, or

```
find ./rgs/test/maes{[1-9],[1-9][0-9],100}/master/stdlist ...
```

for `maes1` -- `maes100` (I didn't get which one was your case).